# iPad Pro screenshot sizes for app review

Tags: ipad, screenshot

I couldn't find any documentation on IPad Pro iTunes connect screenshots sizes.

i tried to look up the screenshot sizes on apple documentation but it does not include the iPad pro yet.

what App Preview and Screenshots sizes should i design to for the iPad Pro?

Answer (score 25):

It is 2048x2732. If you want to create it in xcode 7.1 simulator then you have to set the scale to 100%, otherwise it creates lower resolution screenshot.

Comment: Great tip about setting the simulator scale to 100% for full resolution screenshots!

Comment: You can avoid having to zoom the simulator to 100% by disabling ‘Optimize Rendering for Window Scale’ in the Debug menu of the simulator. This will ensure your screenshots are at the full resolution.

Comment: @Mischinab has the perfect answer - for the iPad Pro simulator, it's impossible to get 100% zoom on all monitors.

Answer (score 12):

It is written in the itunesConnect when you log in to your account.

You can now upload screenshots that are optimized for the iPad Pro. Screenshots for iPad Pro must be 2732 x 2048 pixels or 2048 x 2732 pixels in the JPG or PNG format. They also must be in the RGB color space and can’t contain alpha channels.

Answer (score 2):

(4 years later..)

New requirements are:
[image]

From Apple site: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925